# Run a python script with Popen with PyInstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I need to run a script inside a Popen inside a packaged project (with pyinstaller). The command NEEDS to run in python3 and I (obviously) need it to be portable, which means that I can't rely on the config (python/python3 notation) used on the machine I've used to generate the package neither the one where I am using it (I can't also guarantee that there will be any python in the deployment machine...).

I have computers where python is already the correct version, and others where the correct one is python3. I tried to insert #!/usr/bin python3 in the beginning of the file and then run as python but it didn't work.

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'internal.py', arg1, arg2], universal_newlines=True)
```

In the non-frozen environment I am able to run using `sys.executable` instead of `python`. I tried to "pyinstall" the `internal.py` then, "pyinstall" the rest copying the internal folder to the new folder and then call:

```
subprocess.Popen(['./internal/internal', arg1, arg2], universal_newlines=True)
```

But this doesn't work... In the console (moving to the bigger project folder) it does, but when running the package, it doesn't...

Any idea?

Ps. I can't just import the script as a class or whatever. I can't modify system environment vars (except the ones inside the pyinstaller thing...)

I saw something about the PyInstaller.compat that has a exec_python and a __wrap_python, but I couldn't use it I get errors when trying to run the package due to `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'PyInstaller' distribution was not found and is required by the application`, I tried to create a hook, to add as hidden import... None worked (but the hook part maybe I got it wrong...)

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no :(.... what I ended up doing, I’ve put and if, on mac I import the class, on Windows I call the .exe this causes several changes in code to work both ways

Comment: Ah that's OK. Thanks.